# How to split each word from a string and store it in different variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here's the case, I have a variable with a string

```
var text = "This is a string";
```

Is it possible to take every word, except for the spaces, " ", of this string and put it into a seperate variable? Like for example:

```
var 1 = "This";
var 2 = "is";
var 3 = "a";
var 4 = "string";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create an array like `var array = text.split(' ')` then access individual parts like `array[0], array[1],.. etc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var text = "This is a string";
var splitted = text.split(" ");
console.log(splitted);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'This', 'is', 'a', 'string' ]
```

You can access the individual elements like this

```
console.log(splitted[1]);    // will print is
```